# Sort newsgroup-style posts by date, with 'pinned' or 'sticky' posts at the the top. MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to sort posts for a newsgroup-style app so pinned posts show up first, sorted by date newest first, then all other posts show up sorted by date newest first...with the added twist that a post is only sticky for a specified amount of time: while Date.now() is between two midnight-ed dates.

Each document looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b480e"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "type" : "published", 
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "First! - Sticky today", 
        "author" : "Me", 
        "content" : "This post IS sticky on today: 11/12 < 11/13 < 11/18"
    "isSticky" : {
        "begin" : ISODate("2017-11-12T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "end" : ISODate("2017-11-18T00:00:00.000+0000")
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b480f"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "type" : "published", 
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "Second - Sticky today", 
        "author" : "Me", 
        "content" : "This post IS sticky on today: 11/12 < 11/13 < 11/22"
    "isSticky" : {
        "begin" : ISODate("2017-11-12T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "end" : ISODate("2017-11-22T00:00:00.000+0000")
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b480h"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-10T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "type" : "published", 
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "Third", 
        "author" : "Me", 
        "content" : "Newest NON-sticky post. Never was sticky."
    "isSticky" : {
        ""), 
        "")
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b4811"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-09T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "type" : "published", 
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "Fourth", 
        "author" : "You", 
        "content" : "No longer sticky: 11/09 < 11/13 !< 11/11"
    "isSticky" : {
        "begin" : ISODate("2017-11-09T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "end" : ISODate("2017-11-11T00:00:00.000+0000")
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b4812"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-08T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "type" : "published", 
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "Last", 
        "author" : "Me", 
        "content" : "Never was a sticky post"
    "isSticky" : {
        ""), 
        "")
    }
}
```

...For clarity, these documents are already in the same order I would like them to appear once sorted (so my work is done!). I have tried just sorting by isSticky.begin first, then by date,

```
{ "isSticky.begin":-1, date: -1 }
```

but that will not work to allow sticky posts to 'expire' and return to their place in the list once they are outside the sticky date range, e.g. the post Titled "Fourth" above. It is also a requirement that a post can be retroactively made sticky at any time or can be set to become sticky in the future...so the sticky date range takes precedence over its creation date and the creation date does not have to equal the beginning of the sticky date range.

I'm still a mongo beginner, so I'm sure there's just some concept in the documentation I haven't grokked yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [aggregate pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

This way :

```
> db.posts.aggregate([{$project: {document: "$$ROOT", "s": {$gte: ["$detail.isSticky.end",  new Date() ] } } }, {$sort: {"s": -1, "date": -1}} , {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$document'}}]).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b480e"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-02T00:00:00Z"),
    "type" : "published",
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "First! - Sticky today",
        "author" : "Me",
        "content" : "This post IS sticky on today: 11/12 < 11/13 < 11/18",
        "isSticky" : {
            "begin" : ISODate("2017-11-12T00:00:00Z"),
            "end" : ISODate("2017-11-18T00:00:00Z")
        }
    },
    "s" : true
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b480f"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "type" : "published",
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "Second - Sticky today",
        "author" : "Me",
        "content" : "This post IS sticky on today: 11/12 < 11/13 < 11/22",
        "isSticky" : {
            "begin" : ISODate("2017-11-12T00:00:00Z"),
            "end" : ISODate("2017-11-22T00:00:00Z")
        }
    },
    "s" : true
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b480a"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-10T00:00:00Z"),
    "type" : "published",
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "Third",
        "author" : "Me",
        "content" : "Newest NON-sticky post. Never was sticky.",
        "isSticky" : {

        }
    },
    "s" : false
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b4811"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-09T00:00:00Z"),
    "type" : "published",
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "Fourth",
        "author" : "You",
        "content" : "No longer sticky: 11/09 < 11/13 !< 11/11",
        "isSticky" : {
            "begin" : ISODate("2017-11-09T00:00:00Z"),
            "end" : ISODate("2017-11-11T00:00:00Z")
        }
    },
    "s" : false
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b6dab93294aebe7d8b4812"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-08T00:00:00Z"),
    "type" : "published",
    "detail" : {
        "title" : "Last",
        "author" : "Me",
        "content" : "Never was a sticky post",
        "isSticky" : {

        }
    },
    "s" : false
}
```

The [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage add a "s" field that indicates if the post is stickyand store the document in "document" field.

Then the [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) perform the sort

And [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) replace the root with the document from the $project stage

Comment: This works to see the data sorted properly, but breaks my angular2+ front end because it changes the entire result (by embedding the original document into the document field), so yes, I would like to achieve the same result without that step. Could $project be used to only add the "s" field? I like that I might be able to use that field to display a little pin icon on sticky posts, but I don't like the idea of having to change all my references to this collection to include the "document." prefix.

Comment: That's done. I add a $replaceRoot stage at then end to reset the document